iisnode encountered an error when processing the request. I am trying to put nuxt3 project to local IIS
I am trying to put nuxt3 project to local IIS
iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.
HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP subStatus: 1002
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is 'true'.
In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process, consider using debugging and ETW traces to further diagnose the problem.
You may get additional information about this error condition by logging stdout and stderr of the node.exe process.To enable logging, set the system.webServer/iisnode/@loggingEnabled configuration setting to 'true' (current value is 'false').
How can I fix it?
enter image description here

As long as you dump iisnode and move to HttpPlatformHandler https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-nuxt-3-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Try to add line app.listen(process.env.PORT); in app.js. You can learn more from here
